# Simultaneous multi threading in RISCV

Tags: cpu-architecture, riscv, hyperthreading

In RISCV architecture, does simultaneous multi threading allow threads of two different privilege modes run simultaneously sharing the processor's issue width?

Can OS and application programs share the hart using Simultaneous multi threading?

Comment: I'd assume so; it does on most ISAs.  Otherwise you couldn't have one hart on the same physical core run an interrupt handler while another hart was still running user-space code.  *share the hart* - A "hart" is a logical core (what some people call a hardware thread), or any other way for hardware to look like a multi-core CPU.  So sharing one hart is up to software, e.g. the application program can make system calls, and interrupt handlers could regain control for the OS.

Comment: Privilege and priority are orthogonal concepts.